# how to join two hive tables with embedded array of struct and array on pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, hive

I am trying to join two hive tables on databricks.

tab1:

```
consumer_id (string) question_id                                  some_questions 
  "reghvsdvwe"       "rvsvbetvs-dvewdqwavd-363tr13r"              The contents are shown below
```

The schema of "some_questions"

```
 array<struct<question_id:string, answers:array<struct<answer_id:string, date_made:timestamp, updated:timestamp>>>>
```

"some_questions" example:

```
  0: 
   question_id: "rvsvbetvs-dvewdqwavd-363tr13r" 
   answers: 0: {"answer_id": "4363r23-46745y3-2er296", "date_made": "2006-11-02T00:00:00.000+0000", "Updated": "2006-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000"}

   1: 
     question_id: "rthdcva45-3t342r34y-vdvsdvds"
     answers: 0: {"answer_id": "eewgrg-2353t3-thetber", "date_made": "2006-05-12T00:00:00.000+0000", "Updated": "2006-05-12T00:00:00.000+0000"}
```

tab2:

```
   question_id (string)              answer_id(string)          question_contents            answer_contents
   "rvsvbetvs-dvewdqwavd-363tr13r"   "4363r23-46745y3-2er296"   "what do you like the food?"  "smell is good"

   "rthdcva45-3t342r34y-vdvsdvds"    "eewgrg-2353t3-thetber"    "how do you enjoy the travel ?"      "too much traffic in rush hour"
```

I need to join tab1 and tab2 by "question_id" such that I get a new table

```
 consumer_id    question_id                     question_content              answer_content
 "reghvsdvwe"   "rvsvbetvs-dvewdqwavd-363tr13r"  "what do you like the food?"   "smell is good"

 "reghvsdvwe"   "rthdcva45-3t342r34y-vdvsdvds"  "how do you enjoy the travel ?"   "too much traffic in rush hour"
```

I try to join them by pyspark. But, I am not sure how to decompose the array with embedded struct/array.

thanks

Comment: what is the condition you want to join two tabs on?

Comment: join tab1 and tab2 by "question_id", thanks

Comment: hi, @user3448011, would you mind to add a feedback to my answer?  BTW. are you looking to join by the `question_id` field inside the `some_question` column, or the new `question_id` you added as a standalone column. using the later does not match what is shown in your desired result.

Comment: i need to join them by "question_id" in "some_question", thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SparkSQL, you can use either [exists](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#exists):

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT t1.consumer_id, t2.answer_id, t2.question_contents, t2.answer_contents 
  FROM tab1 as t1
  JOIN tab2 as t2 ON exists(t1.some_questions, x -> x.question_id=t2.question_id)
""").show()
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|consumer_id|           answer_id|   question_contents|     answer_contents|
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| reghvsdvwe|4363r23-46745y3-2...|what do you like ...|       smell is good|
| reghvsdvwe|eewgrg-2353t3-the...|how do you enjoy ...|too much traffic ...|
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

or [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains):

```
spark.sql(""" 
  SELECT t1.consumer_id, t2.answer_id, t2.question_contents, t2.answer_contents 
  FROM tab1 as t1 
  JOIN tab2 as t2 ON array_contains(t1.some_questions.question_id, t2.question_id)
""").show()
```

with PySpark syntax:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df_new = tab1.alias('t1').join(
  tab2.alias('t2'), 
  expr("array_contains(t1.some_questions.question_id, t2.question_id)")
).select('t1.consumer_id', 't2.question_id', 't2.question_contents', 't2.answer_contents')
```